# Using DevDemon Forms, skip empty fields in result email

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-forms

Is it possible to have the results include only fields with results in the admin and user emails?
I have a form that collects data for 3 different possible options. I want to get the data only for the option that was chosen, not all of the empty fields from the other 2 options.

Comment: Could you go ahead and paste a sample from your template? You might need to paste them in a pastie (like http://pastebin.com/) because you don't have privileges to edit your own question yet. Do that a leave link here as a comment.

Comment: Email Template 

<p><strong>Form: </strong> {form:label}</p>
<p><strong>Date: </strong> {date:usa}</p>

{form:fields}

{if field:value}
<p><strong>{field:label}:</strong> {field:value}</p>

 {/if}
{/form:fields}

Comment: Link to form: https://www.armstrong.edu/armstrong/forms/facility_services_vehicle_rental_scheduling
The vehicle Requested item on the form controls which set of fields the user completes. I only want the fields the user completes in the results email.

Comment: Hrmm.. after hitting the Devdemon docs, I'm not sure you can do what you want. What you  need to do is be able to output fields as single variables, but it looks like Devdemon only lets you use a variable pair loop. There could be a really nasty PHP solution, but I'm not sure you'd want it. I also don't know Devdemon so perhaps someone else can chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

You can create a template with the fields manually. Say you have a field called phone.

You can do:

```
{if field:phone}Phone: {field:phone}{/if}
```

Brad